# can php be installed twice?

Tags: php, xampp

if I install PHP and then I install xampp, will PHP be installed twice?

Also please suggest any way to update PHP in xampp or update the total xampp with php and mysql along with it.

Comment: Multiple versions of PHP can be installed, yes. XAMPP, however, generally creates more problems than it solves when installed on Linux. Is there any reason why you cannot use a traditional LAMP configuration?

Comment: actually, I'm using Linux for a few days. I knew the problems xampp creates from my windows days. but not well enough informed about other options.. can you please explain or elaborate.  

btw, did you mean if someone installs PHP first and then xampp in Linux, he shall have two installations of php?

Comment: XAMPP has its own versions of MySQL and PHP, which operate (and occasionally conflict) with packages installed via `apt` or other package managers. XAMPP does a lot of things "in its own way" which is often poorly documented. When I've been asked to work on XAMPP-based systems for clients, 80% of the work is generally spent hunting down problems in XAMPP rather than code. If the plan is to use Linux, do yourself a favour and install Apache, MySQL, and PHP via `apt`. You'll save yourself a ton of headaches and hassle.

Comment: if I install them separately, then I have to configure them manually to use them altogether right?

Comment: It's easier than you think. [Follow this guide from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04). Do not skip steps. You'll have a fully working LAMP stack that can be more easily supported by a much larger group of people on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. You just made my career starter package more flexible. <3